# Installing wordpress in a subfolder of the main wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Okay, I've got a working wp installation **(www.SITEURL1.co.uk)** at the root of **SERVER1** and I want to move another wordpress **(www.SITEURL2.co.uk)** I have in another server **(SERVER2)**, in a subfolder of **(www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision)** right now like this:

- **ROOT(siteurl1)**
- wp-admin
- wp-content etc.
- **(SITEURL1/onlinerevision/)**

  - wp-admin
  - wp-content etc..

So I put the 2nd wp installation files into the given **(www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/)** subfolder. Now I can see the homepage is accessible, the css is not okay and also all the links are redirecting to the **www.SITEURL2.co.uk**

e.g: **www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/login/** is redirected to **www.SITEURL1.co.uk/login/** or

**www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/signup/** is redirected to **www.SITEURL1.co.uk/signup/**

Also **www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/wp-login.php** is **looping in a redirect** to the same page (www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/wp-login.php) and I can't login to dashboard like this:

http://siteurl1.co.uk/onlinerevision/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsiteurl1.co.uk%2Fonlinerevision%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

In the database I opened for www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/, I'm changing the wp_options table -> siteurl from www.SITEURL2.co.uk/ to www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/

but somehow it's turning back to www.SITEURL2.co.uk/

Apparently www.SITEURL1.co.uk and www.SITEURL1.co.uk/onlinerevision/ both have the same htaccess codes:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried different methods but didn't work. Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to exclude calls to the subdirectory in the root .htaccess rewrite rules. In the middle of something but will check back later and answer if it isn't already.

Comment: @Omnikrys I tried this https://support.host1plus.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/798/0/how-to-exclude-subfolders-from-wordpress-permalinks but didn't work. Would be really happy if you could help me solving it...thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that I barely skimmed it earlier. Putting an answer together now but I doubt it is your .htaccess causing the problem. PS since you are using default urls you can just delete them. It won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry got side tracked again.

First, lets address the .htaccess files.

In the root you want to tell it to ignore your second WordPress installation directory.

**/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# Skip your second WordPress installation
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(onlinerevision|onlinerevision/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For the second installation you want to set the RewriteBase then tweak the final rule so it uses it properly.

**onlinerevision/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Set the RewriteBase to this directory
RewriteBase /onlinerevision/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Remove the slash before index.php or we end up at root
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Second, there are two places you need to change the site URL when you move a WordPress installation. They are both located in the **wp_options** table. One is named **siteurl** and the other is named **home**.

I yanked a copy of one of my test sites and moved it to a directory in another test site then set those two .htaccess files and was golden. Most other oddities in a move are related to plugins/themes or URLs embedded in pages/posts. If you still have issues try disabling all themes/plugins to see if it clears up.

**Debugging mod_rewrite**

Also, you can turn on logging for mod_rewrite to help narrow it down. The log can be cryptic but once you figure out how to read it you can usually pick out what is going wrong or at least narrow it down. To do that you need to add a couple lines to the server conf (not htaccess file). A good place is the VirtualHost directive for the site you are having trouble with...

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
    # From 0 (no logging) to 9 (OMFG make it stop)
    RewriteLogLevel 3
```

PS: Logging over 2-3 has a significant impact on your server so only use it when debugging and don't forget to turn it off when done.

Comment: I'm following your answer. Yet I can't find anything called "home" inside the mm_options table :/ **Edit**: fount it a second

Comment: Awesome! Im inside the dashboard now. But when I go to siteurl1.com/onlinerevision it's still saying page not found etc. Also all the links are to the siteurl2.com where it was installed first.

Comment: I have the xml exports from siteurl2.com installation too. Should I import them now? or first need to do any other thing?

Comment: So what is siteurl1.com/onlinerevision running if you haven't loaded the data?

Comment: I just received the xml exports (posts,pages,other plugin exports from dashboard at siteurl2.com) I'm not talking about db exports.

Comment: oh actually, it already has it all. Oh, okay so the only problem I'm still having is the links are still siteurl2.com and when I go to siteurl1.com/onlinerevision it says page not found

Comment: Is the site formatting the links correctly? It should be generating proper URLs at this point (IE: siteurl1.com/onlinerevision/2014/11/02/some-post/). Not where you end up but the links on the pages.

Comment: Nope, it's like this: siteurl2.com/subjects or siteurl2.com/category/gcse

Comment: Now that I'm checking again, on phpmyadmin options it's siteurl2.com again! I changed it already!?

Comment: Make sure the dashboard isn't open in a browser and that you are looking at the correct database in phpmyadmin. This might be easier... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64057/wordpress